# How would you update a frontend form with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, user-meta

I'm trying to build me own frontend AJAX updating screen mirroring interface.

I have a very basic form:

```html
<form id="mblocation">
    <input type="radio" name="mb_user_location" id="mb_user_location1" value="1" checked="checked">
    <label for="mb_user_location1">
        <span>in office</span>
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="mb_user_location" id="mb_user_location2" value="2">
    <label for="mb_user_location2">
        <span>out of office</span>
    </label>

    <input type="hidden" name="mb_user_id" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="mb_location_nonce_field" name="mb_location_nonce_field" value="6b8a75521b">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/inout/">
</form>
```

And I want to have an AJAX script run every `x` seconds based on what the
administrators set in the options page `get_option('mb_heartbeat_time')`:

```js
function mb_ajax_updater( mb_heartbeat_time ) {

    // get the user id
    var mb_user_id = $('input[name="mb_user_id"]').val();

    // get the user current location
    var mb_user_location_current = '<?= get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'mb_user_location_current', true ); ?>';

    // get the current :checked location
    var mb_user_location_checked = $('input[name="mb_user_location"]:checked').val();

    // is the saved location and the checked the same
    if( mb_user_location_current ==  mb_user_location_checked ) {

        // log the result
        console.log( 'Result: same location!' );

    } else {

        // save the new meta
        // how to get the current location?
        // how to get the previous location?
        <?php update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'mb_user_location_current', ????? ); ?>
        <?php update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'mb_user_location_previous', ????? ); ?>

        // update the view
        $("input#mb_user_location" + mb_user_location_checked ).prop( "checked","checked" );

    }

    // set the timer
    setTimeout( mb_ajax_updater, mb_heartbeat_time );
}

// run it first time
mb_ajax_updater( <?= get_option('mb_heartbeat_time'); ?> );
```

But I'm not exactly sure where I'm supposed to go from here. How do I validate
that the ajax is being sent from the `get_current_user_id`? How do I add the PHP
parts so the `update_user_meta` will update? Is there a better way of doing this, 
than what I'm attempting?

All I want to do is when one screen is updated, reflect it on the other screen in
the time allocated by the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being:

```js
<script>
var mb_user_location_current = ...
...
</script>
```

And then used those variables from the `head` to the function.

But then ventured down other paths for different solutions.